# Problemas com Progress-bar em Flip card

Tags: html, css

Olá, amigos, como vocês estão ?

Estou com problemas em relação a um Progress bar em um card com animação de Flip.
Aparentemente, o progress bar entra certo, porém, com o efeito do mouse em cima do card, ao dar o Flip, a progress-bar fica da direita para a esquerda e não da esquerda para a direita.

Já tentei usar:

```html
direction: rtl;
direction: ltr;
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

porém, nada da certo.
Gostaria de entender melhor o que tá acontecendo de fato e a melhor solução para este probleminha.

Trecho do código:

```css
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  }
  
  /* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  /* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
  .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  /* Position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
  .flip-card-front {
    background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Style the back side */
  .flip-card-back {
    background-color: rgb(19, 48, 77);
    color: rgb(68, 68, 70);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
   <div class="flip-card-inner">
     <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h1> HTML </h1>
     </div>
     <div class="flip-card-back progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%;">
    <p>90%</p>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Como podemos reproduzir o código? No snippet acima não mostra nenhuma barra de progresso em funcionamento.

Comment: A animação não há, nem literalmente a classe progress, porém, se alterar as características da DIV, poderá observar que ao alterar o valor da porcentagem da barra de progresso, você verá ela em funcionamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione `right: 0` na classe `.flip-card-back`. Como a parte de trás é invertida em 180 graus, a orientação do elemento será contrária (da direita para esquerda). Alinhando o back para a direita com `right: 0`, haverá uma nova inversão na orientação do elemento (da esquerda para a direita).

No exemplo abaixo criei uma pequena animação para ilustrar:

```js
$(function(){
   $(".flip-card").hover(
      function(){
         $(".progress-bar").animate({ width: "100%" }, 1000);
      },
      function(){
         $(".progress-bar").css("width", "10%");
      }
   );
});
```

```css
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  }
  
  /* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  /* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
  .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  
  /* Position the front and back side */
  .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
  .flip-card-front {
    background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Style the back side */
  .flip-card-back {
    background-color: rgb(19, 48, 77);
    color: rgb(68, 68, 70);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: red;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-card">
   <div class="flip-card-inner">
     <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h1> HTML </h1>
     </div>
     <div class="flip-card-back progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;">
    <p>90%</p>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!